# How to output a list of POST data which Zend_Http_Client will send?

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, post, zend-http-client

I need to debug my Zend_Http_Client code so that I am sure that I am sending all of the proper POST fields & headers to my server. How can I output the list of the POST fields which will be sent, or even what the entire HTTP command will be?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I missed it [right in the documentation:](http://www.havedoc.com/zend/latest/codedoc/page/Zend_Http/Client/Zend_Http_Client.html#getLastRequest) `getLastRequest()` will return a stringified version of the entire last request!

Comment: BTW for more advanced testing there is also the Test ZHC adapter, but it is probably not needed unless you intend to write unit tests to test your use of ZHC.